# Why cant i change this string? - Python

Tags: python, string

I have got this string:

```
test = "access-list [a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+ deny any\n"
```

and i have this variable:

```
regex = r"[a-zA-Z0-9_/-]+"
```

now i want to change the original string, i want to subtract the variable value in the string and insert another one. so that i get something like this.

```
test = "access-list new_value deny any\n"
```

i have tried to do this, but it failed:

```
test_replacement = test.replace(regex, "new_value")
```

Comment: Use `re.sub`...

Comment: Python doesn't have regex support for `string.replace`. You have to use the `re` module.

Comment: Code looks like good. Can you please explain exactly which error you are getting?